# Changing the Django-CMS default icon for links

Tags: django, icons, default, django-cms

The contents of placeholders in Django-CMS can be modified with the provided frontend editor, which includes a basic plugin for inserting links. By default, this plugin shows a square "blue globe" icon in the editor preview where the link will appear. I'd like to change what icon appears, preferably to a text representation of the link rendered as an image. Is it possible to modify the existing link plugin, or would I have to make a new plugin with this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build your own link plugin for that which defines the [icon_src](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/extending_cms/api_references.html#cms.plugin_base.CMSPluginBase.icon_src) method which has to return a URL to a image.